# Can't convert to JST timezone on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, commando

I'm trying to convert `input` date to japan timezone with this code

```
var japanTime = new Date(input).toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "Japan" });
        japanTime = new Date(japanTime);
        message.channel.send('JAP time output: ' + japanTime.toLocaleString());
```

It runs normally on Visual Studio Code but when I deploy it on heroku and try to convert any date, I got this error `RangeError: Expected Area/Location(/Location)* for time zone, got Japan`

Answer (score 1):

The [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) time zone identifier for Japan is `Asia/Tokyo`, not `Japan`